# iOS bluetooth's CBCentralManager not scanning devices after separating files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to get a list of bluetooth devices nearby and display it in a UItableview.

Originally I have this written in one view controller file using storyboard, and it worked, but now I'm separating the files to TableViewController, TableDelegate and TableDataSource, and writing this programmatically, and I'm not sure how to split the file up into 3 and have it work. This is what I have so far. It compiles, but CBCentralManager never scans the devices and call the centralManagerDidUpdateState function

The original code:

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0) {
        if (![_foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
            NSLog(@"Found: %@", localName);
            [_foundPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
            [_adData addObject:advertisementData];
            [_RSSI addObject:RSSI];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            //peripheral.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}

// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        NSArray *services = @[kDFUServiceUUID, kGuinnessServiceUUID, kHeartrateServiceUUID, kBatteryServiceUUID, kDeviceInfoServiceUUID];
        NSDictionary *scanOptions = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)};
        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:scanOptions];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.deviceData = nil;
    _foundPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _adData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _RSSI = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.centralManager = centralManager;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [_centralManager stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Segues

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.foundPeripherals count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    CBPeripheral *peripheral=[_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = peripheral.name;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

New, separated code that doesn't work.

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableDataSource.h"
#import "TableDelegate.h"

@interface TableViewController () {
    TableDataSource *_dataSource;
    TableDelegate *_delegate;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.view = tableView;
    _dataSource = [[TableDataSource alloc] init];
    _delegate = [[TableDelegate alloc] init];
    _delegate.controller = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = _dataSource;
    self.tableView.delegate = _delegate;
    [self.tableView registerClass: [UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: @"device"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_dataSource getBluetoothDevices];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"reloadTable"
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(checkRes:) name:@"reloadTable" object:nil];
}

-(void)checkRes:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"reloadTable"])
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

TableDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface TableDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *controller;

@end
```

TableDelegate.m

```
#import "TableDelegate.h"
#import "TableDataSource.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableDelegate () {
    TableDataSource *_dataSource;
}

@end

@implementation TableDelegate

- (instancetype)initWithDataSource:(TableDataSource *)dataSource {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    _dataSource = dataSource;
    return self;
}

// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        NSArray *services = @[kDFUServiceUUID, kGuinnessServiceUUID, kHeartrateServiceUUID, kBatteryServiceUUID, kDeviceInfoServiceUUID];
        NSDictionary *scanOptions = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)};
        [_dataSource.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:scanOptions];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [_controller.navigationController pushViewController: detail animated: YES];
}

@end
```

TableDataSource.m

```
#import "TableDataSource.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableDelegate.h"

@interface TableDataSource () {
    TableDelegate *_delegate;
}

@end

@implementation TableDataSource

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(TableDelegate *)delegate {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    _delegate = delegate;
    return self;
}

- (void)getBluetoothDevices
{
    _foundPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _adData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _RSSI = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:_delegate queue:nil];
    self.centralManager = centralManager;
}

// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0) {
        if (![_foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
            NSLog(@"Found: %@", localName);
            [_foundPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
            [_adData addObject:advertisementData];
            [_RSSI addObject:RSSI];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTable" object:self];
            //peripheral.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}

// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        NSArray *services = @[kDFUServiceUUID, kGuinnessServiceUUID, kHeartrateServiceUUID, kBatteryServiceUUID, kDeviceInfoServiceUUID];
        NSDictionary *scanOptions = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)};
        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:scanOptions];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [self getBluetoothDevices];
    return [self.foundPeripherals count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"device";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    CBPeripheral *peripheral=[_foundPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = peripheral.name;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: What you have done doesn't really make sense - By splitting your class into three you need provide the appropriate data to each class instance - For example, your MasterViewController has the array that contains the discovered peripherals - so you need to provide that array to the class instance that is your table data source.  Simply implementing the CBCentralDelegate methods in the data source class won't do it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know how to split up the CoreBluetooth methods into different files. What methods should I put in the delegate file and data source file?

Comment: Either don't or you could move your CBCentralManager into its own class but you will need to establish a protocol for that class to communicate with the other classes in your app.  You rarely separate the datasource and table view delegate methods from the controller class

Comment: So I'm better off just having my previous class where everything is in one method?

Comment: Certainly as far as table methods go - You could move Bluetooth out if it makes sense - you need to design your app classes to suit your needs.

Comment: A CoreBluetooth manager singleton could be a solution.

Comment: I also have an app displaying BLE devices in a table view. We use `BluetoothManager` class, which creates `CBCentralManager` and acts as a `CBCentralManagerDelegate`. It does some filtering (we don't show unsupported devices) and wraps `CBPeripheral` instances into wrapper objects. Then passes an array of these objects to the data source (which is BluetoothManager's delegate). The data source is a plain NSObject subclass conforming to UITableViewDataSource protocol.